# What's the point in modelling the base mesh?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

On a thread, I saw someone mentioning that sculpting leads to triangle faces which I myself saw happened to me lately but I find myself sculpting for the final touches even after modelling it 60 percent. Is there a point in modelling at all if I can just sculpt the entire thing from start to get the same result (I really don't wanna model the entire ting from start to final product) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my personal view, based on my own experience, so some others may see things differently: Sculpting from scratch is possible, but works best with purely organic forms which don't have a lot of lengthy or technical structural features. If they do have these, then it can be expedient, I believe, to begin with a modeling process instead of a sculpting process. You can use both processes, of course, and alternate between them. It can sometimes be efficient to begin with a modeling process and move over to a sculpting one, once the overall structure is in place, and you now want to create finer details. You can also get a lot of good use out of booleans when sculpting because the resulting topology issues aren't yet a concern. Also, bear in mind that sculpting only leads to triangle faces when Dyntopo is enabled. If disabled, sculpting brushes only push vertices around, but don't actually change the topology, which is one possible approach that might be more compatible with a workflow that switches back and forth between modeling and sculpting. So don't discount the use of both methods. I would never want to suggest that one of these methods is always preferable to the other.

Comment: I see. I was modelling a female character and stuff like joints looked better when I sculpted them in instead of making cuts with knife but the tutorials kept using the knife cuts instead of just sculpting them in so I thought there was a un-written rule followed there

Comment: Yeah, I think maybe what was going on there, if I had to guess, is that the author of the tutorial was focusing on creating a low-poly base mesh, which would later either control or be converted to a higher resolution mesh. In this case, it might make sense to use the cuts, since the poly count remains currently at a minimum.

Comment: One thing I didn't make clear about the possible advantages of beginning with  a modeling process over a sculpting one, even on an organic character, is the "sense of proportion" problem. This is more an artistic consideration than a technical one, but sometimes it's easier to start with modeling because it gives your whole subject a sense of proportion that you can then reference as you continue to develop it. This is harder to gauge when you start sculpting right off the bat. Or, at least, it takes more time to finalize the base shape without the aid of modeling tools.